# Nuxtjs: Expose localhost to external doesn't work

Tags: mobile, host, nuxt.js

I try to connect my mobile to my local nuxtjs project. I thought it would be easy as described there. https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/ but nothing works. I have also installed cross-env but didn't solved my problem.

If I start npm run dev on my pc

```
"dev": "cross-env NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0 NUXT_PORT=3333 nuxt",
```

the server starts and I can connect to the project with the url

[image]

But if I try to connect with my mobile, it doesn't load. My mobile and pc are connected to the same wifi.

I tried to find out which ip nuxtjs sets in the url, if there is maybe the problem. I used ipconfig and in the first entries I found the ip but there are many others and I have no idea for what they are... [image]

I have also taken a look in the settings of my wifi, but there I found a different ip-address
[image]

Is that the problem? I tried to set this ip in NUXT_HOST, but then I only get this error message

```
listen EADDRNOTAVAIL ip-address
```

Any ideas? Ah I'm using windows 10 if that makes a difference.

**SOLUTION**

**On the mobile the IP from the wifi + the port which was set in the nuxt.config is required, not the IP that gets outputed in the console**

Comment: I think a firewall is causing your problem.
But first, have you tried pinging your pc in the network e.g. with your phone?

Comment: @confusius I pinged the ip and it was sending 4 packages and received
 4 and time was 0ms. So that works, I shutted down my firewall and tried to load the page on my mobile, but same result. Can't access the page...

Comment: @GregorVoinov, have you solved this?

Comment: @claudios yes. You have to enter on your mobile the IP from your wifi + the port which was defined in the nuxt.config.

Answer (score 38):

I hope I understand your question correctly.

If you are asking for a way to allow Nuxt development server to allow connections from (external) hosts and ip addresses other than localhost, this is easily done by modifying `nuxt.config.js` as such:

```js
    build: {
        extend(config, ctx) {} // blah blah
    },
    server: {
        host: "0.0.0.0"
    }
```

I use this to connect to Nuxt from my mobile phone via Wi-Fi over my local network.

Answer (score 16):

For me to share my Nuxt dev-website on my local network (to debug on other devices like phones and tablets) I did the following.

**1.**

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

**2.**

I changed the "dev" command in my package.json to

```
"dev": "cross-env NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0 NUXT_PORT=3333 nuxt",
```

**3.**

I ran `npm run dev` and got the following

[image: NUXT sharing localhost on your network - mobile debugging]

**4.**

I visited the address given to me in the console on other devices. Worked very well.

Comment: if it's not working try add "dev" at the end
"dev": "cross-env NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0 NUXT_PORT=3333 nuxt dev",

Answer (score 11):

There're a couple of ways of doing that. Here's the [official doc](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/).

For example:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3333 nuxt"
}
```

or direct command:
`nuxt --hostname myhost --port 3333`

etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had success with Leopold's method after also setting Windows 11 Network Settings to "Private Network" for the wi-fi network. I suspect this indicates issue with firewall settings - my next step was to check Node firewall settings but the "Private Network" trick worked. Good luck!